# What is the correct match of dependencies between NextJS13 and Sanity?

Tags: next.js, sanity, next.js13

I'm trying to deploy a NextJs project using Sanity at the backend  side, at deployment this error occurs:

```
[13:36:44.275] Retrieving list of deployment files...
[13:36:44.750] Previous build caches not available
[13:36:44.799] Downloading 72 deployment files...
[13:36:45.460] Running "vercel build"
[13:36:45.926] Vercel CLI 28.10.0
[13:36:46.203] Installing dependencies...
[13:36:46.521] yarn install v1.22.17
[13:36:46.563] [1/4] Resolving packages...
[13:36:47.744] [2/4] Fetching packages...
[13:36:57.604] [3/4] Linking dependencies...
[13:36:57.606] warning " > next-sanity@3.1.9" has incorrect peer dependency "next@^13".
[13:37:07.243] [4/4] Building fresh packages...
[13:37:07.517] success Saved lockfile.
[13:37:07.520] Done in 21.00s.
[13:37:07.555] Detected Next.js version: 12.2.2
[13:37:07.556] Running "yarn run build"
[13:37:07.799] yarn run v1.22.17
[13:37:07.820] $ next build
[13:37:08.210] info  - SWC minify release candidate enabled. https://nextjs.link/swcmin
[13:37:08.366] Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
[13:37:08.366] This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
[13:37:08.366] You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
[13:37:08.367] https://nextjs.org/telemetry
[13:37:08.367] 
[13:37:08.624] info  - Linting and checking validity of types...
[13:37:11.901] info  - Creating an optimized production build...
[13:37:17.601] info  - Compiled successfully
[13:37:17.601] info  - Collecting page data...
[13:37:19.578] info  - Generating static pages (0/3)
[13:37:19.717] (node:466) ExperimentalWarning: The Fetch API is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
[13:37:19.718] (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
[13:37:19.723] 
[13:37:19.724] Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
[13:37:19.724] TypeError: fetch failed
[13:37:19.724]     at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11118:11)
[13:37:19.724]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[13:37:19.724]     at async fetchSkils (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/index.js:1197:17)
[13:37:19.724]     at async getStaticProps (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/index.js:1091:20)
[13:37:19.724]     at async renderToHTML (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:451:20)
[13:37:19.724]     at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/export/worker.js:251:36
[13:37:19.724]     at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
[13:37:19.725] info  - Generating static pages (3/3)
[13:37:19.725] 
[13:37:19.725] > Build error occurred
[13:37:19.727] Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
[13:37:19.727]  /
[13:37:19.727]     at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:395:19
[13:37:19.727]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[13:37:19.727]     at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
[13:37:19.728]     at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:1094:21
[13:37:19.728]     at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
[13:37:19.728]     at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:971:17
[13:37:19.728]     at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
[13:37:19.728]     at async Object.build [as default] (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:64:29)
[13:37:19.762] error Command failed with exit code 1.
[13:37:19.762] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
[13:37:19.779] Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
```

After reading docs about the issue, I found that, the build cannot fetch data at this level during deployment( but it works fine on development side):

```
export const getStaticProps:GetStaticProps<Props> = async () => {

  const skills: Skill[] = await fetchSkils();
  const projects: Project[] = await fetchProjects();
  const pageInfo: PageInfo = await fetchPageinfo();
  const experiences: Experience[] = await fetchExperience();
  
  
  return {
    props: {
      pageInfo,
      experiences,
      skills,
      projects,
    },
    revalidate:1000,
   
  };
};
```

I think that the mismatch between dependencies is the reason for it:

```
warning " > next-sanity@3.1.9" has incorrect peer dependency "next@^13".
```

So anybody knows what dependencies can work well together??

Comment: It sounds to me that `fetchSkills`, `fetchProjects` and friends are calling internal endpoints (a.k.a functions on `api` folder), can you confirm if this is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I discovered that these are not dependancy erros,  The deployment process of NextJS deploys the elements in the API folder at the end, that's why the datas cannot be fetched early. I just move those files out from the API folder and everything solved.